# Why is the sprintf_s giving different result in different versions of Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rounding, stdio

```
sprintf_s(buf, "%.*f", 14, 0.182696884245135);
```

in VS2008 = 0.18269688424514

in VS2015 = 0.18269688424513

Was the behavior for sprintf_s changed? How can I get the old behavior?

Answer (score 9):

We rewrote the floating point parser and formatter for [the Universal CRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx) and Visual C++ 2015 to improve correctness.  See the [Breaking Changes in Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb531344.aspx) documentation for Visual C++ 2015; there is a section entitled "Floating point formatting and parsing."

The Visual C++ 2015 result is the correctly rounded result.  The input string `0.182696884245135` is converted to the following double precision value, which is the closest representable value:

```
0.18269688424513'49994693288181224488653242588043212890625
```

Note the tick mark after the 14th fractional digit.  The 15th digit is a `4`, so when formatting the number with 14 fractional digits, the number is "rounded down" (or truncated), not up.

The Visual C++ 2008 result is incorrect.  I do not know whether error was introduced during parsing or formatting.  There is no way to get the old, incorrect behavior with the Universal CRT and Visual C++ 2015.

Comment: Thank you for your answer James. This change however caused a problem for our customers. sprintf_s(buf, "%.*f", 2, 0.155) now causes 0.15 instead of 0.16 for example. Is there a way to mimic the old sprintf_s behavior through other rounding functions?

Comment: That is also the correct result:  The closest representable value there is `0.154999...`, which rounds down to `0.15` not up to `0.16`.  The old implementation rounded incorrectly in both directions (up and down).  There's no other way to get the exact same incorrect behavior short of using the old implementation (by using Visual C++ 2013 or earlier). You can certainly try to do numeric comparisons to see "is this thing pretty close to the halfway point?" (for some definition of "pretty close") and adjust the number yourself as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Vs2008 was using 80bit floating point literals and was rounding this more precise value when converting to a double.

Vs2015 doesn't do this and merely truncates the literal.

I believe you can toggle between the two schemes by changing the compiler settings.

Comment: The Visual C++ 2008 result is actually less correct.  See my answer for details.

Comment: You're the expert! I'll delete this and upvote your answer.

Comment: Before I do tin it though could you confirm that vs2008 didn't use 80 bit literals by default? (Ie the out of the box compiler settings). I recall seeing something like this a few years ago.

Comment: `double` is always 64-bit double precision IEEE-754 in all versions of Visual C++.  The compiler supports different target architectures. Under `/arch:IA32` the 80-bit x87 FPU is used; under `/arch:SSE2`, the SSE instruction set is used, with 64-bit precision.  At some point we changed the default target architecture from IA32 to SSE2; I do not recall which release, but certainly sometime between 2008 and 2015. You can still compile with `/arch:IA32` using Visual C++ 2015 though, you just have to explicitly pass that setting.  But...

Comment: ...the target architecture setting does not affect the floating point parser and formatter.  Those use a library implementation.  In Visual C++ 2013 and older versions, a software 12-byte floating point implementation is used to perform the conversions.  In the Universal CRT and Visual C++ 2015, a high precision integer implementation is used. The new implementation offers better correctness and is sometimes more efficient.